# compile-time check of correctness of dictionary entry type with interfaces

Tags: c#, types, interface, compiler-errors

I am looking for a way to define an `IDictionary<List<IInterface>, HashSet<IInterface>>` so that for each key-value pair, the type that implements `IInterface` is the same.

Let's say I have two types `T1`, `T2` that implement `IInterface`.

Then it should be possible to add a key-value-pair of types

1. `List<T1>` and `HashSet<T1>`
2. `List<T2>` and `HashSet<T2>`

but it should NOT be possible to add a key-value-pair of types

1. `List<T1>` and `HashSet<T2>`
2. `List<T2>` and `HashSet<T1>`.

Is it possible to define such a dictionary so that I get a compile error whenever I try to add a forbidden key-value-pair? If yes, how?

I don't care if I need one or several new classes, interfaces etc. for that. I just want to know if it is possible in principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't care if I need one or several new classes, interfaces etc. for that.

Well in that case it's mostly possible! You can wrap a non-type-safe dictionary in a class which only provides type-safe access.

```
public class MyDictionary {
    private readonly Dictionary<object, object> _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    public void Add<T>(List<T> key, HashSet<T> value) where T : IInterface {
      _innerDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
    public HashSet<T> Get<T>(List<T> key) where T : IInterface {
      return (HashSet<T>)_innerDictionary[key];
    }
    public void Set<T>(List<T> key, HashSet<T> value) where T : IInterface {
      _innerDictionary[key] = value;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Note that `List<ConcreteImplementation>` is not convertible to `List<IInterface>`, regardless of whether `ConcreteImplementation` implements `IInterface`, so you cannot implement the `IDictionary<List<IInterface>, HashSet<IInterface>>` interface this way.